# In a list, if a contiguous set of items satisfies a given condition, replace them by a sublist containing those items

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of items `L` and I have a function to check some condition. For example that condition could be to check if an item is a non-number. And the list could be `[1, 2, 'a', 'c', 'x', 5, 7, 'w', 'r', 10, 12, 'q', 4]`.

I want to replace a contiguous (adjacent) streak of such items by a sublist containing those items in the same order. So in this case, the output would be: `[1, 2, ['a', 'c', 'x'], 5, 7, ['w', 'r'], 10, 12, ['q'], 4]`. Is there any elegant/fast way of reliably doing this?

I've currently coded it as a loop that keeps track of indices and the whole thing looks very brute-forcey and inefficient, hence the question.

Comment: Hello, So if you are looking for a more efficient code, please post your code snippet that does the logic here as it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? Not really a huge fan of this solution though - using `itertools.groupby` to create groups, only to unpack some of the groups seems redundant.

```
def group_str(items):
    from itertools import groupby

    def is_str(item):
        return isinstance(item, str)
    
    for key, group in groupby(items, key=is_str):
        if key:
            yield list(group)
        else:
            yield from group

grouped = [*group_str([1, 2, 'a', 'c', 'x', 5, 7, 'w', 'r', 10, 12, 'q', 4])]

print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, ['a', 'c', 'x'], 5, 7, ['w', 'r'], 10, 12, ['q'], 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to split your list according to whatever logic you need. In this case, I grouped ints and strings, and either appended or extended another list to produce the result you need.

```
from itertools import groupby


def keyfunc(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return "str"
    elif isinstance(item, int):
        return "int"
    else:
        return "unk"


somelist = [1, 2, "a", "c", "x", 5, 7, "w", "r", 10, 12, "q", 4]

groupedlist = []
for k, g in groupby(somelist, keyfunc):
    if k == "int":
        groupedlist.extend(g)
    elif k == "str":
        groupedlist.append(list(g))
print(groupedlist)
```

Cheers!